# Let $F$ be a linear operator such that $F^2 - F + I = 0$, show that $F$ is invertible and $F^{-1} = I - F$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I didn't understand this exercise. I tried working with

$$F^2 - F + I = 0\implies (F-I)(F) + I =0$$

but I really don't understand how to prove $F$ is invertible neither find the inverse. Any hints? Thank you so much!

Comment: Move $I\,$ to the other side of the equation (and note that $F$ commutes with $I-F$ so it's a two-sided inverse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take what you have,
$$(F-I)F+I=0$$
This means
$$(F-I)F=-I$$
so
$$(I-F)F=I$$

Note also that
$$(I-F)F=(F-F^2)=F(I-F)=I$$

Thus $F^{-1}=I-F$.

Comment: Technically, I think you also should show that _I_ - _F_ is a right inverse by calculating _F_ (_I_-_F_).

Comment: @BernardMassé Edited, thanks.

Comment: @BernardMassé I do not think it is necessary. A (square) matrix is invertible if and only if it has a left inverse.

Comment: @CameronWilliams For an infinite-dimensional space though there are left invertible linear transformations that are not right invertible.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm aware (the shift operators are the simplest cases) but I think it's pretty clear that this is a basic linear algebra question, not a functional analytic question.

Comment: Of course! Something multiplied by $F$ that gives the identity, is its inverse. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: can $0$ be an eigenvalue of $F$?

Hint 2: can you multiply $F^2-F+I=0$ by $F^{-1}$ once you know it exists?

Comment: Minor nitpick: the question did not say this was an operator on a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Well, it's easy to show that $F$ is surjective. ;-)